# Signature in Front is getting resized in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, signature

I am trying to create a signature in [front](https://front.com/). I was able to insert the image by saving it on the computer and uploading it. After messing around with the formatting it looks fine on Front. The problem arises when sending an email and opening it up on the Outlook app. The image size gets blown up. [The image part of the signature is larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBiXv.png). When opening the image on both Outlook Online and also on mobile, the image looks the correct size [Image looks fine on Outlook Online.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIclx.png). I tried adjusting the DPI of the image to both 75 and also 55 [found this solution here](https://blog.gimm.io/how-to-fix-email-signature-images-changing-size/#:%7E:text=If%20your%20DPI%20settings%20are,DPI%20setting%20on%20the%20image.). Neither of these solutions worked. I tried saving, and uploading the image as a .gif .jpg .png and all of these also didn't work. I tried going into the HTML and changing the size of the image there and that also didn't work. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1.Create a new message, then copy and paste the image you need in the message body.

2.Click and drag the box around the image to resize the image to the size you want.

3.Save the image.

4.[Create a new signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-email-signature-in-outlook-3a139d75-256e-4f0f-8351-e0cc02810b9c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) and insert the image.

Comment: I did try this you can't copy and paste images into Front they have to either be uploaded from the computer or a URL. Also I tried uploading the image from the computer and resizing it in Front and it still would change the size on Outlook.

Comment: If you cannot copy/paste, can you drag and drop the picture into the email body?